# slice bounds out of range [:9] with capacity 6

Tags: go, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a Golang app that would take the data from a Google Sheet (which has in total 9 columns, some with info some blank) and then output to a .csv separated by "|".

However, during the output i get this error: **panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:9] with capacity 6**

here's my code:

```
    spreadsheetId := "xxx"
    readRange := "MASTER!A1:I"
    resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).ValueRenderOption("FORMATTED_VALUE").Do()
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }

    file, err := os.Create("result.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot create file", err)
      }
      defer file.Close()

    for _, row := range resp.Values {

      row = row[:9]
      
      data := fmt.Sprintf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8])
      var dataNew = data
      dataNew = strings.Replace(dataNew, "\n", "", -1)
      fmt.Fprint(file, dataNew + "\n")
    }
```

While it manages to perfectly output over 20 rows into a .csv, it crashes then it reaches a row that only has 6 cells with some value, with other cells empty.

If i remove **row = row[:9]** - the app panics on row 5 that has 7 cells with values out of 9 in total. The error message is: **panic: runtime error: index out of range [7] with length 7**

I'm fairly new in Go, so I'm not entirely sure what's the problem here.

Comment: My guess would be for the rows that are short (less than 9 entries) the slice (row) only has as many items as the row had. The values being ranged over are not uniform in length. Add a fmt.Printf("count = %v\n", len(rows)) just inside the for loop (before the row[:9]) and see. You will need to check the length of rows before accessing the it.

Comment: Here's the output below after adding fmt.Printf("count = %v\n", len(row)). It seems odd that it can handle different variations of length but crashes when it's gets to anything below 6.

count = 9
count = 9
count = 9
count = 9
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 9
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 8
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 7
count = 9
count = 7
count = 7
count = 6
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:9] with capacity 6

Comment: @PitaHat: it _crashes_ because you are indexing outside the length of the slice, which should not be surprising. If the short `resp.Values` slices are surprising, then you need to see what the guarantees are of that package's API.

Comment: @JimB I see. I think it also has to do with the empty values in row[6] - it can process if row[6] has actual value on the Google Sheet, yet panics it's empty. Similarly though, if row[7] is empty, the program understands it and outputs a blank nil value, which all just makes me confused more. In other words, why can't it do the same for row[6].

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join operation in the rows instead of manually indexing each item. For instance :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    rows := []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
    data := strings.Join(rows, "|")
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Which will print :

```
1|2|3|4|5
```